# Why won't my SKSpriteNodes appear in the scene?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am trying to add a couple of nodes to the scene. When I run the app I just have the default gray background. Neither of the nodes appear in the scene. Here is what I have:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        let jumper = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Jumper")
        jumper.xScale = 0.25
        jumper.yScale = 0.25
        jumper.position = CGPointMake(50, 300)

        self.addChild(jumper)

        let blob = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Blob")
        blob.position = CGPointMake(160, 30)
        blob.xScale = 0.5
        blob.yScale = 0.25

        self.addChild(blob)
    }
```

I have checked the image titles and everything is correct there.

Comment: Does didMoveToView get called when you put a breakpoint in it?

Comment: Your textures might not be rendering properly. Try setting the color to black as well as the colorBlendFactor to 1.0 to verify whether the nodes are bein placed at all.

Answer (score 12):

The Problem

Your sprites are not visible because your scene is not completely within the simulator's window. By default the scene's size is 1024 x 768 (specified by GameScene.sks), while the simulator is displaying only 375 x 667 points (if you selected the iPhone 6/6s simulator). Unless the scene's size is set correctly, the bottom-left corner of the simulator's window will not be the (0,0) position of your scene.

To correct this issue,

**Method 1:**

Change the scene's size property in GameScene.sks to match the size of the view. I suggest you set the scene size to 375 x 667 (iPhone 6/6s). If you do this and set the scene's `scaleMode` property to `.AspectFill` (the default value), SpriteKit will automatically scale the scene to fit in the view of the iPhone 6+, 6s+, 5, and 5s. This will save you time when porting your game to these devices.

**Method 2:**
In your view controller, replace this

```
scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
```

with this

```
scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
```

Warning: Using this method will work but may require additional effort to port your game to other iOS devices with a different screen size.

Comment: This helped me. Why the hell does xcode not do this for you? Seems ridiculous to have such default behaviour.

Comment: @JasonMcCarrell another, perhaps better, way to correct the scene's size is to set the scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill in the view controller. If you do this, the scene's size is automatically set to the view's size.

Comment: Awesome dude. I'll try it later. I'm assuming this means I can forgo the size calculating jazz and simply set scaleMode to ResizeFill.

Comment: @JasonMcCarrell yes, setting `scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill` is all you need to do.

Comment: Just came across this while I had a similar issue only my sprites were randomly showing at each run. Turns out that I set  [ignoreSiblingOrder](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skview/1520215-ignoressiblingorder) to `true`. Making that `false` or explicitly specifying zPosition solved it. Also, note that _not_ ignoring the order might have [performance implications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30008486)