# importance/Efficiency of skView.ignoreSiblingOrder in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

How important/efficient is it to do `skView.ignoreSiblingOrder = true` when initializing a scene?

Right now, I have it set to true, but for some reason when I start my GameScene from my MainMenu scene, it loads the background before my character (even though the backgound's code comes first) but it fixes once I die and go back to main menu and then load another game scene. To avoid that issue, I have made a boolean that basically detects when I've played more than one game. It's functional right now but very ugly and i'm sure there is a better way.

Code:
(In touchesBegan)

```
                    let skView = self.view as SKView!
                    skView.showsFPS = true
                    skView.showsNodeCount = true
                    if spriteNode.name == "StartButton"
                    {


                        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */

                        //sets ignoreSiblingOrder to false the first game because of XCode Glitch where background was rendering over player for some reason
                        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = false
                        if(Game){
                            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
                        }

                        if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene
                        {
                            skView.presentScene(scene)
                            /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
                            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

                        }
```

GameSceneCode:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)
{
    TheGame = SKNode()
    self.addChild(TheGame)

    createSky()
    createGround()
    addFireButton()
    addJumpButton()
    addHero(view)       

}
```

To reiterate, for some reason the first game I play the background renders after(so over) my hero and buttons even though the `createGround()` function runs after. Here are the functions below.

```
func addHero(view: SKView){
    //initializes our hero and sets his initial texture to running1
    hero = SKSpriteNode(texture: heroAtlas.textureNamed("10Xmini_wizard"))
    hero.xScale = 0.4
    hero.yScale = 0.4
    hero.position = CGPointMake(frame.width / 4.0, frame.height / 4.0)

    //creates some CG values for the hero to be used in its physics definitions
    let heroSize = CGSizeMake(hero.size.width, hero.size.height)
    let heroCenter = CGPointMake(hero.position.x/2, hero.position.y/2)
    self.addChild(hero);

}

func createGround()
{
    let groundTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bg")
    groundTexture.filteringMode = .Nearest

    let moveGroundSprite = SKAction.moveByX(-groundTexture.size().width * 2.0, y: 0, duration: NSTimeInterval(0.01 * groundTexture.size().width * 1.0))
    let resetGroundSprite = SKAction.moveByX(groundTexture.size().width * 2.0, y: 0, duration: 0.0)
    let moveGroundSpritesForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([moveGroundSprite, resetGroundSprite]))

    for var i:CGFloat = 0; i < 2.0 + self.frame.size.width / (groundTexture.size().width * 2.0); ++i
    {
        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: groundTexture)
        sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: groundTexture.size().width, height: frame.height/8))
        sprite.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        sprite.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
        sprite.setScale(2.0)
        sprite.position = CGPointMake(i * sprite.size.width, sprite.size.height / 2.0)
        sprite.runAction(moveGroundSpritesForever)
        TheGame.addChild(sprite)
    }
}
```

Comment: i think this code is for running the player right? i want to sliding that player can you please tell me how to do it?as am beginner in swift sprite kit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When `ignoresSiblingOrder` is false, SpriteKit renders nodes in the order they exist in their parent's `children` array — that is, the array order determines which one draws "on top of" the other. It also means SpriteKit has to render each node one at a time, so you're losing efficiency to OpenGL draw call overhead.

When `ignoresSiblingOrder` is true, SpriteKit relies exclusively on the `zPosition` property for figuring out what order to draw in. This means it can sometimes combine everything at the same z into a single draw, which makes rendering faster. But it also means that if you want to control which nodes draw in front of which others, you need to set their `zPosition` appropriately.

Comment: So do you have any idea why the first time I run the scene it glitches but all times after it's fine? Also, can you further explain how to see the 'zPosition' so that my background will always render first?

Comment: As for the first question... You're ignoring sibling order, so there's no guarantee what order you'll get. As for the second... What does [the documentation for `zPosition`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/zPosition) tell you?

Comment: Taken from: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKView/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKView/ignoresSiblingOrder When this property is set to "true", the position of the nodes in the tree is ignored when determining the rendering order. The rendering order of nodes at the same z position is arbitrary and may change every time a new frame is rendered.

Comment: Is it possible for a parent node to be rendered on top of a child node ? Assuming we set ignore sibling order to true and the child node has a zPosition of 0.