# What is the relative order of a child with no zPosition (0)?

Tags: sprite-kit, zposition

I read the Sprite Programing guide and they describe how children's zPosition is based off it's parent.

For example if parent has 100 zPosition and the child has 1 zPosition. 
The child will have a relative (to scene) zPosition of 101. 
Assuming that ignoreSibling order is set to true, for efficiency.

Using this logic:
If a child doesn't have a zPosition or a zPosition of zero, will it's relative zPosition be the same as it's parent ?

For example: 
If parent has a zPosition of 100 and child has a zPosition of 0. 
Child has a relative zPosition of 100.

If this is true it means that we should always set our children's zPosition to 1 in order to avoid the possibility of the parent being rendered on top of the child.

I read similar questions but they seem to ignore the case where a child doesn't have a zPosition.

Comment: depend of ignoresiblingorder var: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30008486/importance-efficiency-of-skview-ignoresiblingorder-in-swift

Comment: @simone yes assuming that it's set to true.

Comment: So is right your sentence "If this is true it means that we should always set our children's zPosition to 1"