# How Do I Reconfigure Coordinate Plane in Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am experimenting with SpriteKit. As a template, it opens with this:

```swift
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, _ withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    // Touch code here
}
```

It passes a `touches` parameter that is a set of all the current touches, and their positions on the screen. When I click on the screen in the area that should be `(0,0)`, the CGPoints are off by near 120? How can I recalibrate and position the scene to be at `(0,0)`?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: yes I've tried disabling auto-sizing but the problem still persists. I am fairly new and don't know what to do

Comment: It's literally the template when you start a sprite kit game :

import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
       
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */
        
        for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            
           println(location)
        }
    }

Comment: See the answer to this question. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25233506/why-wont-my-skspritenodes-not-appear-in-the-scene)

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/q/25205882/2158465

Comment: None of these fixes have worked? In fact, it made it worse. It's like I'm zoomed in too much now. Anyone else have any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

After experimenting for a bit I have found a fix for the issue. The scene size by default is (1024, 768) and the view size by default is (667, 375).

This code fixes the problem:
scene?.size = self.view!.frame.size

I am concerned that I should have to configure this and I feel I am missing a configuration setting on creation of a project. Is this something they forgot to set up by default with Xcode or am I missing something?